# ¿Cómo paso un input value a un url.action en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formularios, asp.net-mvc-5, input-type

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ingresos" placeholder="Ingrese su mail" aria-label="Username" name="Email" id="usuario">

<input type="password" class="form-control ingresos" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" aria-label="Username" Name="Contraseña" id="contrasena">

<input type="button" class="boton" value="Login" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Verify" , "Home", new { Email="hola", Contraseña="123" })'" />
```

Comment: vas a necesitar usar JS o JQuery para eso o podes usar un form, ahi evitas usar JS

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar esto, necesitas tener un modelo y que tu metodo Post reciba este modelo

```
@model YourApplication.Controllers.ExampleController.Modelo
<form action="Url.Action("Verify","Home")" method=Post>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Email)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Contraseña)
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

En tu controller recibis el modelo en cuestion

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Verify(Modelo credentialsmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string email= credentialsmodel.Email;
            string contraseña = credentialsmodel.Contraseña;

            //hacer algo aqui y luego redirect
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            //modelo invalido
            return View(credentialsmodel);
        }
    }
```

El modelo en cuestion

```
    public class Modelo
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email requerido")]
        public string Email{ set; get; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contraseña requerida")]
        public string Contraseña { set; get; }

        public CredentialsModel() { }
    }
```

Referencia https://forums.asp.net/t/1944581.aspx?Passing+values+from+View+to+Action+Method+using+href+Url+Action+